# How to move to a particular page details of Datatable based on page number click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable on page, manipulation of table entries has been done by selection of "Number of entries per page" and next, previous buttons also available.

Just in case, there are 100 entries available in table and i selected Entries per page as 10. Then the next and previous will be +1 and -1 towards page details to see.

Can i see the page details as per the number click..?

like <(previous) Page: 1 2 3 4 .... (next)>

The numeric numbers, by clicking the number itself i want to see..

can any one help on this...?

Comment: What have you tried, what _exactly_ is your question? What you want is some kind of pagination which is implemented on 70 quadrillion sites.

Answer (score 0):

use grid view and make true for paging it will automatically make page what u like